# sum the amount on 3 sets of multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to do some calculation (SUM) on 3 sets of multidimensional array few days ago but I have yet to find any solution after research online.

My array looks like this:

```
$arrayOne = array(
    0 => array(
        "x"=> "Jan",
        "y"=>100
    ), 
    1=> array(
        "x"=> "Feb",
        "y"=>"20"
    )
);


$arrayTwo = array(
    0=> array(
        "x"=> "Feb",
        "y"=>"30"
    )
    1=> array(
        "x"=> "Mar",
        "y"=>"70"
    )
);


$arrayThree = array(
    0=> array(
        "x"=> "Jan",
        "y"=>"20"
    )
);
```

Expected Output:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        "x"=> "Jan",
        "y"=>120
    ), 
    1=> array(
        "x"=> "Feb",
        "y"=>"50"
    ), 
    2=> array(
        "x"=> "Mar",
        "y"=>"70"
    )
);
```

I saw from the forum, in order to get the SUM, i need to build the function on my own, and I have tried to modify one of the example shared by Peter:

```
function sumFromArray($arrayOne, $arrayTwo, $arrayThree)
{
    foreach ($arrayOne as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($arrayTwo[$key]['y'])||isset($arrayThree[$key]['y'])) {
            $arrayOne[$key]['y'] = $value['y'] + $arrayTwo[$key]['y']+ $arrayThree[$key]['y'];
        }
    }

    return $arrayOne;
}
```

With the function above, I noticed that if $key is missing on $arrayOne, I'm not able to show the SUM of that $key on the result. With the function above, I'm getting the output below, **"x"=>"Mar", "y"=>"70"** is missing.

```
array(
    0 => array(
        "x"=> "Jan",
        "y"=>120
    ), 
    1=> array(
        "x"=> "Feb",
        "y"=>"50"
    ), 
);
```

Can anyone please enlighten me on parts that I need to edit? I tried to use if...elseif... else... to control but end up the script is not functioning.

Should I merge the all 3 arrays into one before I do the calculation?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php- add elements of 3 arrays and save it in a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37592427/php-add-elements-of-3-arrays-and-save-it-in-a-new-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function multiArraySum($arrayList = [])
{

    $m = [];
    $months_details = [];
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($arrayList as $arrayItem) {
        foreach ($arrayItem as $subArray) {
            if (isset($months_details[$subArray['x']])) {//if month is exist
                $m[$months_details[$subArray['x']]]['y'] += $subArray['y'];
            } else {
                $months_details[$subArray['x']] = $i;
                $m[$i] = ['x'=>$subArray['x'], 'y'=>$subArray['y']];
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }    
    return $m;

}

$arrayOne =[
    0 => [
        "x"=> "Jan",
        "y"=>100
    ], 
    1=> [
        "x"=> "Feb",
        "y"=>"20"
    ]
];


$arrayTwo = [
    0=> [
        "x"=> "Feb",
        "y"=>"30"
    ],
    1=> [
        "x"=> "Mar",
        "y"=>"70"
    ]
];


$arrayThree = array(
    0=> [
        "x"=> "Jan",
        "y"=>"20"
    ]
);

print_r(multiArraySum([$arrayOne,$arrayTwo,$arrayThree]));
```

Comment: "Try This" answers are "low value" on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and future researchers.  When you do not attempt to educate, you create a dependency loop whereby user continue to post question after question and rely on others to write their code for them.  Please improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arrays = array_merge($arrayOne, $arrayTwo, $arrayThree);

$result = [];
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
  if (!isset($result[$array['x']])) {
    $result[$array['x']] = [];
  }

  $sum = isset($result[$array['x']]['y']) ? $result[$array['x']]['y'] : 0;

  $result[$array['x']]['x'] = $array['x'];
  $result[$array['x']]['y'] = $array['y'] + $sum;
}
```

Result

```
array (size=3)
  'Jan' => 
    array (size=2)
      'x' => string 'Jan' (length=3)
      'y' => int 120
  'Feb' => 
    array (size=2)
      'x' => string 'Feb' (length=3)
      'y' => int 50
  'Mar' => 
    array (size=2)
      'x' => string 'Mar' (length=3)
      'y' => int 70
```

Comment: "Try This" answers are "low value" on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and future researchers.  When you do not attempt to educate, you create a dependency loop whereby user continue to post question after question and rely on others to write their code for them.  Please improve your answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for your comment, I will try to improve my answers next time :)

Comment: Never too late to improve this one.  The Edit button is available 24/7.  This is not a public shaming.  I sometimes don't explain my answers as much as I could, but when I realize that I can provide a better answer, I take a couple of minutes to truly help others with some thoughtful explanation.  (This is also a great way to improve your own skills by stepping through your logic AND potentially earn points by helping future researchers.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputArray[] = [0 => ["x"=> "Jan","y"=>100], ["x"=> "Feb","y"=>"20"];
$inputArray[] = [0 => ["x"=> "Feb","y"=>"30"],["x"=> "Mar","y"=>"70"];
$inputArray[] = [0=> ["x"=> "Jan","y"=>"20"]];

$finalArray = getSum($inputArray);

var_dump($finalArray);

function getSum($data){
  $finalArray = [0 => ["x"=> "Jan","y"=>0],["x"=> "Feb","y"=>0],["x"=> "Mar","y"=>0];
  foreach($data as $inputArray){
     foreach($inputArray as $input){
        if($input['x'] == 'Jan')
          $finalArray[0]['y'] += $input['y'];
        if($input['x'] == 'Feb')
          $finalArray[1]['y'] += $input['y'];
        if($input['x'] == 'Mar')
          $finalArray[2]['y'] += $input['y'];
     }
  }
  return $finalArray
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are "low value" on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and thousands of future researchers about how your solution works and why it is a good solution.  If you truly want to help, then answer with the intent to educate. Furthermore, your solution is not very flexible because it hardcodes the "known" months "in-play".  Without knowing the months, you'd need to write out all 12, then remove the unused ones.  Not great, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The following should sum the `y` array key in your multidimensional array. It can hold as many arrays as you want.

#### Code

```
function sumFromArray()
{
    $resultArray = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < func_num_args(); $i++) {
        foreach (func_get_arg($i) as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($resultArray[$key])) {
                $resultArray[$key]['y'] += $value['y'];
            } else {
                $resultArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $resultArray;
}
```

#### Usage

```
$arrayOne = array(
    0 => array(
        "x"=> "Jan",
        "y"=>120
    ), 
    1=> array(
        "x"=> "Feb",
        "y"=>"50"
    ),
);

$arrayTwo = array(
    0 => array(
        "x"=> "Jan",
        "y"=>20
    ), 
    2 => array(
        "x" => "Feb",
        "y" =>"90"
    ), 
);

$arrayThree = array(
    0 => array(
        "x"=> "Jan",
        "y"=>120
    ), 
    1=> array(
        "x"=> "Feb",
        "y" => "60"
    ),
);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(sumFromArray($arrayOne, $arrayTwo, $arrayThree));
```

#### Result

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["x"]=>
    string(3) "Jan"
    ["y"]=>
    int(260)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["x"]=>
    string(3) "Feb"
    ["y"]=>
    int(110)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["x"]=>
    string(3) "Feb"
    ["y"]=>
    string(2) "90"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain _how_ your answer works.  Telling the OP that it _should_ work and that it can handle infinite arrays, does little to educate the OP and future researchers about how it works and why it is a good solution.